# Why is the camera list showing “Sonix Technology Co Ltd.” instead of “Integrated Camera?”

Tags: windows-11, lenovo-laptop, webcam, camera, obs-studio

I’m trying to set up OBS with my webcam and integrated camera, but in the cameras list it shows up with my webcam, but instead of “Integrated Camera,” it shows up with “Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.,” same thing Settings and Zoom.

For some reason the “Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.” camera listing doesn't have any output. Is there any way to revert it back to the “Integrated Camera?”

- **PC**: ideapad Gaming 3-15IMH05 Laptop - Type 81Y4
- **Processor**: 1x 10th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-10300H Processor(Core™ i5-10300H)
- **Memory**: 1x 16GB DDR4 2933 (2x 8GB)
- **Operating System**: Windows 11 Home 64(EN:English)
- **Integrated Camera**: 1x 720P HD with Dual Array Microphone
- **Graphics**: 1x GeForce GTX 1650 4GB

Camera Drivers:

> [image]

Comment: ok, and? is there a question?

Comment: My bad, was in a rush and forgot to add that part

Comment: Have you tried going to Device Manager, click on the device and choose Properties 
find the driver(s), there may a button which shows "Roll Back Driver".
- - Or maybe open the Windows Update, find the update which installed the 
Sonix driver(s) and unistall the update. ?

Comment: @vssher Rolling the driver back worked, thanks!